# trouble with jquery loading a file that has CSS and JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using jquery.load to load an html. I get the HTML, but not its CSS or JS. I get a "SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'"

My main page is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="js/jquery-3.3.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<body>
<button onclick="jqueryLoadStep()">click me</button>
<div id="content"></div>

<script>
    function jqueryLoadStep(){
        $('#content').append('<div id="new1">add new page here</div>');
        $("#new1").load("subdir/step1.html", function(){
            //loadStepXML(n); //translated texts
        });
    }
</script>
</body></html>
```

and the page being loaded in is

```
<link href="4.css" rel="stylesheet">
<body>
   <div id="target"> I'm step 1 </div>
   <script src="4.js"></script>    
</body>
```

the error:

```
SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'[Learn More] simple.html:1
DOMEval
```

and it points to `doc.head.appendChild( script ).parentNode.removeChild( script );`

Question, what am I missing to get jquery.load to load a page with it's CSS and JS intact?

Comment: Probably you forget to add the script tag (<script src="4.js"></script>) before end of body tag. I see you put it after close tag of body element. So put it just before body close tag.

Comment: I changed it so the <script> is inside the body, same error.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a html tag with new1 id element?

Comment: ...or one with ID 'content'  (' new1' is generated by the JS function)